# If $A \subset X$ has no limit points in itself, then it is discrete.

Tags: general-topology, limits

If $A$ has no limit points in itself, then for every $x \in A$ there is a neighborhood $U $ such that $U$ intersects $A$ with no element other than $x$.

My approach:

Any $U$ other than $\{x\}$ contains other elements of $A$. So $U = \{x\}$ for $A$ not to have limit points in itself.

It is simple, does showing only open neighborhood that could satisfy the hypothesis is the singleton set, since $U$ is an open neighborhood than the singleton set is open really make $\{x\}$ open? This just doesn't seem right to me. It is more of contradiction with $A$ having no limit point in itself.

Comment: A set other than the empty set cannot be intrinsically open. It can be open in some space, but not in another.  If  $p\in A$ is not a limit point of $A$ with respect to the topology on $X$ then $\{p\}$ is open in the sub-space $A$ of the space $X$ although $\{p\}$ may or may not be open in $X.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition: $x$ is a limit point of $A$ iff for every open neighbourhood $O$ of $x$ we have that $O \cap (A\setminus\{x\})  \neq \emptyset$

So if no point of $x \in A$ is a limit point of $A$, this means logically that

$$\forall x \in A: \exists O_x \text{ open }: x \in O \text{ and } O_x \cap ( A \setminus \{x\}) = \emptyset$$

Then for these $O_x$ we have $O_x \cap A = \{x\}$ (right to left inclusion is clear,as $x \in O_x$ and $x \in A$, while the left to right inclusion is clear from: suppose $y \in O_x \cap A$, if $y \neq x$ it would be a point in $O_x \cap (A\setminus \{x\})$, contradiction, so $y = x$).

Then for all $X \in A$, the singleton $\{x\}$ is open in the subspace topology of $A$, as it is of the form $O_x \cap A$ for an open set of $X$. And so *all* subsets of $A$ are open in the subspace topology and $A$ is discrete (as a subspace of $X$).